# Escape percent sign in SQL query regex?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

This query works:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "[[:<:]]100[[:>:]]"
```

But this doesn't. It returns nothing, but I have a value "100%" on my table.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "[[:<:]]100%[[:>:]]"
```

How can I make the query with the percent signal?

Comment: Use a backslash. See: `\%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. You've got to change the character class `[[::>::]]` to something else that matches your need, because the percent sign is no word character, see [REGEXP documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. **A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_)**.

If it could be followed by i.e whitespace or punctuation or the end of the string then you could use

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE content REGEXP '[[:<:]]100%([[:blank:]]|[[:punct:]]|$)';
```

You can see in [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deee7/1) that you don't have to escape the percent sign (even you could do it).

The percent sign makes the use of the word end boundary not applicable anymore. You have to find a combination of other markers that will do for you.

Comment: This happens when you are a REGEX newbie. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `%` is not a special character in regular expressions.

You should be able to just fire off:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[[:<:]]100%[[:>:]]'
```